# jQuery Skills Diagram with Raphaël not working if two other custom jscripts are also running

Tags: jquery, runtime-error, diagram, incompatibility

I have the following scripts called on a site:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
<script defer src="js/jquery.flexslider-min.js" ></script>
<script src="js/jquery.carouFredSel-6.1.0-packed.js" ></script>
<script src="js/modernizr.html"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.gmap.js"></script>
<script src="js/skrollr.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/raphael.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/init.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

*raphael.js* and *init.js* set up a Skills Diagram ([as found here](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/04/22/animated-skills-diagram/)). The issue is that the diagram doesn't work unless I disable both *scripts.js* and *main.js* (which are custom scripts and I'm including them in the 'NOT WORKING' Fiddle).

If I place *raphael.js* and *init.js* above the other two, then the Diagram is partially built. So evidently the other two scripts, together (because if I omit one or the other nothing changes), are causing something to not happen or happen incorrectly in one or the other of the two scripts, *raphael.js* and *init.js*.

I've been trying to find what exactly occurs in both *scripts.js* and *main.js* that could be causing either *raphael.js* or *init.js* to fail. Maybe someone out there can figure it out, because it's a mystery to me.

**WORKING: [In this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VzQuT/), the normal diagram, without those problematic scripts, is working fine.**

**NOT WORKING: [In this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5a3cD/1/), I'm including the *script.js* and *main.js* scripts and, voilá, the diagram no longer works: it disappears!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**OK! Found the answer! YAY!**

Well, I know how to fix it, but am not sure WHY it was broken in the first place. Though I suppose one of the scripts I'm including is setting things so that jQuery functions can't be just introduced by `$(...)...` but, rather, need to be inside `jQuery.noConflict()(function($){ ... }`. So, for what it's worth, I had to wrap these pieces of code in the *init.js* with the above call:

```
jQuery.noConflict()(function ($) {
  $('.get').find('.arc').each(function (i) {
    var t = $(this),
      color = t.find('.color').val(),
      value = t.find('.percent').val(),
      text = t.find('.text').text();

    rad += 30;
    var z = r.path().attr({
      arc: [value, color, rad],
      'stroke-width': 26
    });

    z.mouseover(function () {
      this.animate({
        'stroke-width': 50,
        opacity: .75
      }, 1000, 'elastic');
      if (Raphael.type != 'VML') //solves IE problem
        this.toFront();
      title.stop().animate({
        opacity: 0
      }, speed, '>', function () {
        this.attr({
          text: text + '\n' + value + '%'
        }).animate({
          opacity: 1
        }, speed, '<');
      });
    }).mouseout(function () {
      this.stop().animate({
        'stroke-width': 26,
        opacity: 1
      }, speed * 4, 'elastic');
      title.stop().animate({
        opacity: 0
      }, speed, '>', function () {
        title.attr({
          text: defaultText
        }).animate({
          opacity: 1
        }, speed, '<');
      });
    });
  });
});
```

AND

```
jQuery.noConflict()(function($){
  $(function(){ o.init(); });
});
```

If anyone out there know how to explain the *WHY*, then your welcome to add to this answer and educate us further!